# What way to go for real time web experience in Asp.net / Asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, websocket, real-time, signalr

I'm gonna start developing a single page web application using **Microsoft** stack. In some critical parts of the project I have to provide real time data.
I can use **Signalr** or **Web Sockets** for these kind of tasks. Can you do a comparison of them in terms of usability, performance or learning curves of these technologies. And I'm glad to know if you have another option to suggest.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go with signalR. It is part of .net framework, it also supports web sockets and if any client doesnt support web sockets it will fallback to long-polling, forever frames any other technology available.

[.NET 4.5 WebSockets vs SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524591/net-4-5-websockets-vs-signalr)

http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/signalr/signalr-and-web-sockets

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/YourUsersDontCareIfYouUseWebSockets.aspx