# Does socket.io and node.js's performance get affected on heroku's server (with no websocket)?

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

Since heroku server doesn't support websocket, does it mean if we run a node.js + io.socket app on it, expecting many concurrent users, some in effectiveness will happen when there are more users?

I was building a multiuser app and suddenly notice that heroku is using long poll instead of websockets. I couldn't see much delay in my prototype but I am worried, should i be building my app on a server that supports real websockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... should i be building my app on a server that supports real websockets?

Probably.

http://websocket.org/quantum.html, says "HTML5 Web Sockets can provide a 500:1 or—depending on the size of the HTTP headers—even a 1000:1 reduction in unnecessary HTTP header traffic and 3:1 reduction in latency."

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just realised that I am worrying a thing that doesn't really affect me. In a nutshell, I am building my first node.js messaging/chat app. But the clients are going to be iOS apps. So, whether heroku has supports for websockets, which is intended for browser, shouldn't affect my app's performance in anyway because my app should be talking to the heroku server in TCP directly (my ios app is now magically using long poll to talk to server).

Answer (score 0):

Long polling is old and inefficient, and is slowly being replaced by sockets. They are supported by every server. Most of latest browsers have already added support too. Heroku will do that too, soon hopefully. You can continue with your prototype, maybe websocket support will be added before you finish it.

The advantages websocket are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028770/html5-websocket-vs-long-short-polling)