# What's the best way to be able to continously be able to receive WebRTC calls in browser?

Tags: proxy, websocket, webrtc, vline

Need to be able to continuously receive calls when a Chrome webpage is open. How do I do that even for users who are inside a strict enterprise network?

WebSockets? (but there's the proxy problems that doesn't know what wss:// is)
HTTP? (but will I have to poll?)
Other?

Answer (score 0):

Since you included the "vLine" tag, I'll reply with some information on how our WebRTC platform will behave in an enterprise network. [vline.js](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/) will use a secure WebSocket by default if the browser supports it and fall back to HTTPS long polling. As described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Proxy_traversal), the secure WebSocket may work depending on the exact proxy configuration. Feel free to test it out by using [GitTogether](https://gittogether.com) or [creating your own vLine service](https://vline.com) for testing.

Comment: How would websockets perform better than http long polling and why to prefer websockets?

Comment: With regard to the proxy, I'm not sure that WebSockets would necessarily be any better (if both are HTTPS). However, performance-wise a WebSocket is generally better than long polling, which is really a hack: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10029326