# popup alert message across all tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, web

We are developing web messaging application. When we open our website URL into a tab, we able to do chat with our client. But when we switch another tab and client send message us we want to popup a notification message visible from all opened tab. I got few website who are giving this type of notification visible from all tab.

Is there any javascript or flash solution for it?

Comment: Several options to do that. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028770/html5-websocket-vs-long-polling-vs-ajax-vs-webrtc

Comment: what url you sent me? i am not looking for websocket or long polling.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the problem is...

Comment: notification message visible from all browser tab

Answer (score 0):

If you use JavaScripts `alert("");` to create a popup, your browser will automatically go to the tab where the popup was created

so when you receive the message to your webpage call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("you have a message");
});
```