# Facebook notifications web sockets vs. pulling?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, soa, software-design

I'm a developer at enterprise social network product,  and I'm working on a  feature that is very similar to Facebook notifications. 
We want to provide a  notifications mechanism for our customers in real time.

I'm building a notifications service in node.js that my system can interact with and notify.
The biggest issue is:

1. should the client use pulling? I mean every few sec check the service of there are any changes?
2. Implement the client with websockets (socket.io) so the server knows all the available users and push them each change.

The maximum amount of users I will ever acquire is 20k
The maximum amount of active users is 5k

What do you think is best?

Comment: -1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028770/html5-websocket-vs-long-polling-vs-ajax-vs-webrtc

Comment: Thx, couldn't find it. I got the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like socket.io.  Give it a try, it will probably get you started.  But someday you will probably end up needing to dive into the details of how it works, if you're working on a serious commercial product.  For example, WebSockets may get stymied by corporate firewalls, but socket.io will fall back to other methods like polling automatically.