# A timeline monitor for Kendo-Scheduler

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-scheduler

I'm trying to build a monitoring page for a Telerik Scheduler in MVC and trying to refresh the page every minute. I can-do a reload() every minute but was hoping for a more elegant solution. I'm trying the following code in javascript
However I don't see the time-bar updating.

```
  setInterval(function () {

    var scheduler = $("#ReservationsTimeLine").data("kendoScheduler");

    var start = Date.now();
    var end = start + 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    scheduler.startDate = start;
    scheduler.endDate = end;
    scheduler.dataSource.read();
    scheduler.refresh();

  }, 60000);    //1 minute
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of elegant solutions to your problem [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028770/html5-websocket-vs-long-polling-vs-ajax-vs-webrtc-vs-server-sent-events).

I'm not sure what 'time-bar' means but I've noticed that your code refreshes only the scheduler, not the page.