# Can I force refresh content/page using Spring Boot and JSP?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-boot, page-refresh

I am newbie at spring and generally webdev. I am writing small application in spring boot, where on hompage I display actual weatherstatus. Data is storage with help of JpaRepository and HSQLDB.

Each minute I recive data, parse, and add it to repository. The logic is done.

How to force client's browser to refresh, when I get new, actual Data?

Comment: May be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling

Comment: A more involved approach would be including websockets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028770/in-what-situations-would-ajax-long-short-polling-be-preferred-over-html5-websock.   I've been using it in our project for about a year now and while there's a learning curve, it's fairly good.

Answer (score 0):

**With HTML:**

To add this kind of feature without using any Ajax feature, you can use the following meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://thetudors.example.com/'" />
```

- https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html

**With Javascript:**

If you can add Javascript in the project, my advice is to create a endpoint to check periodically with JQuery or Fetch:

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch

Juan Antonio

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `REST` calls then it will be very easy for you.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         setInterval(getWeather(),2000);
         //Here get weather is a method and 2000 is numbers of milliseconds after which you want to update weather data
     });

     function getWeather(){
         $.ajax({
             type : 'GET'
             url  : 'Your url here'
             success : function(data){
                 //set received data to your container
             }
         });
     }
</script>
```