# How to set transports for SocketIO in Android?

Tags: android, socket.io, transport

I spend a long time to research about transports in SocketIO Android.
I need set transports for Options is "websocket" instead of "polling",
Maybe Socketio set default transport is polling.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use the `transports` option:

```
import io.socket.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket;

//...
IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
opts.transports = new String[] { WebSocket.NAME };
Socket mSocket = IO.socket("http://example.com/", opts);
```

For polling:

```
import io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling;
//...

opts.transports = new String[] { Polling.NAME };
```

You can check this [socket.io test](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/blob/e7cc10808cafd381727076bacf1fdb0ccb74e7a2/src/test/java/io/socket/client/ServerConnectionTest.java#L312)

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked for me, but I don't know that when I need use websocket or polling ?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028770/in-what-situations-would-ajax-long-short-polling-be-preferred-over-html5-websock

Comment: Thank you so much, I understood