# Refresh rate for AJAX chat application

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax, chat

I am developing a website which, among other things, allows users to **chat in real time** with one another (similar to Facebook chat). Messages are stored in MySQL table `messages`, which contains ID of the message, sender ID, receiver ID and time.

When user A is chatting with user B, I get all their messages by SQL statement `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (senderID='userA' AND receiverID='userB') OR (senderId='userB' AND receiverID='userA')`. This statement retrieves all the messages between user A and user B.

When chat is opened, I send an **AJAX request** every second (should it be less/more?) to check if there are any new messages between these two users in the database.

**My questions are:**

- How demanding is it for database to run that kind of SQL statement every X seconds when there are a lot of messages in the database?
- Is my approach good enough if there are thousands of requests made every minute?
- Is there any better/faster way of determining if user A sent a new message to user B and then displaying it in the chat window?

Comment: You are the best qualified person to answer these questions by load testing your implementation on the production-level hardware.  It also depends on how your tables are configured and if they have the appropriate indexes for your queries.

Comment: You might want to read this about when you want to use what kind of reuqests [In what situations would AJAX long/short polling be preferred over HTML5 WebSockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028770/in-what-situations-would-ajax-long-short-polling-be-preferred-over-html5-websock)

Comment: Beside that a subscription and publication based system should have the best performance for this kind of application.

Comment: Thank you, I will check out HTML5 websockets. Do they allow multiple users to chat at the same time or is it limited to one opened conversation at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) for this but if you really want to go with polling this is how you could do it:

Your system should hold *Conversations*, *Users* or *Participants* and *Messages*.

- When *John* starts a conversation for the 1st time with *Mary*, you create a new *Conversation*, with a unique `conversation_id`. The *Participants* to that conversation are *Mary* and *John*.
- When a user first opens a past *Conversation*, you `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE conversation_id = 'xyz'`.
- From then on when John sends a message to Mary you simply `INSERT` that message in your database.
- When Mary sends the next polling signal she includes in her message the *last* `message_id` she received. This allows you to `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_id > 115 AND conversation_id = xyz`.
- Mary then appends to her existing list of messages the new messages.

This assumes that `message_id` is an auto incremented column.

Other pointers:

- Prefer [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) over long-polling. They are more efficient because communication between server/clients happens only when needed, i.e when a message is sent.
- Prefer a non-blocking server technology, like NodeJS. Chat applications revolve around small data being sent extremely frequently back and forth. Traditional server technologies like PHP don't deal well with these circumstances.

Comment: Did you mess up with the names in your 3rd bullet point? It doesn't make any sense for me.

Comment: @BillO Yes - I've fixed it.

Comment: @BillO I'd like to point out that using WebSocket's instead of polling will make this much more scalable and make it far easier to avoid doing any `SELECT`'s when a new message is sent.

Comment: One thing though is, I wouldn't fetch all from messages, but rather `LIMIT` them to like 20 or 30, or whatever the business case might be.